# Duda con tipo de consulta en controladores, laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

Bueno, inquietud es si es posible insertarse una consulta con sql normal en un controlador, sin necesidad de query builder o eloquen, si se pudiera, como se podria insertar?

Comment: yes, usando Raw.. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#running-queries

Comment: Gracias JeffCasino